# How do I retain the quality of text in a GIMP png uploaded to Facebook?

Tags: fonts, gimp, png

I used Gimp to create a quote image and I uploaded it to Facebook. I made sure to only use web-safe colors, and the fonts I'm using are Impact Condensed and Arial. However, the uploaded image drastically loses quality and the fonts aren't sharp/surrounded by a fog/are blurry:

Before uploading:
[image: Image generated by GIMP]

After uploading:
[image: Image uploaded to Facebook]

If you open the images in a new tab, you can see the difference between the two clearly.

[image: Close up of corrupted font]

I tried enabling/disabling Interlacing (Adam7) and the other export settings, but I haven't been able to make a difference. All help appreciated.

Comment: That moment when I have the same issue with another image that I *didn't* create and this is the top Google search result.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial image is smaller than the one you download from FB. So, it has been rescaled by FB and there is not much you can do in Gimp since text doesn't scale well.

But perhaps FB is rescaling the image because you didn't provide the picture in some expected standard size. What happens if you use a 1375x92 image?

Since your image is all text another solution would be to use a vector image (SVG). These are supported by all modern browsers (but support by FB has to be checked).

Comment: These are screenshots of the image zoomed in to show how the text is different on my computer vs. when uploaded to Facebook. The image size of both the original image and uploaded image is 650x325. I'll look into creating an svg. I had considered that but just assumed Facebook wouldn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answer, but...

I was having trouble on Twitter images.  Finally, I did a little looking for "what is the best size for a Twitter image."  As I recall, the proportions for that was 7x6. Don't know about Facebook.

If the image is not proportioned correctly, or even just bigger or smaller,  Facebook may be doing some resizing which could lead to some fuzziness or distortion.  Of course, make sure the image has enough resolution too.

Build it in the best size  and you may see improvement.  Its worth a shot to see if it helps.

Comment: My image is 650x325, so 2:1. So I would have to try making the image 700x600?

Comment: Nope. I copied my xcf and moved the objects around to match 525x488 which is roughly 7:6 and I'm still getting the font blur. 700x600 and 350x300 were too large and small for my quote, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to get the best quality you have to resize art such that no interpolation is needed.  E.g., you'll get much better quality dropping it to 50% than to 62%, even though the latter is bigger.  The difference comes from the need to work out how to represent surviving fragments of pixels.  This is particularly bad with type, which is where good hinting comes in.

Comment: I only tried to resize it at xenoid's suggestion. The image is the exact same size on both my computer and Facebook.

Comment: I dunno.  I just now pulled the 2 images into p'shop 7, and couldn't see a lot of difference.  I see some resizing artifacts in the second image, but the number and anti-aliasing of the actual pixels looks pretty much okay to me.

Comment: I added a close-up of the second image. Basically I'm seeing a checkered pattern of grey in-between, above, and below each of the letters.

Comment: If you mean an irregular, indistinct pattern in the background area, they're the resizing artifacts I mentioned.  They might be what's bothering you about it.  What I did was look at the dot over the i, because it's regular and if there's anything funny going on it'll be visible there as well as anywhere.  I didn't see anything funny.  The anti-aliasing isn't identical in both cases, but it does involve the same number of fading pixels.

Comment: I just took a look at your new image.  That's much more regular than the artifacts I saw and normally see when there's been resizing.  I'm not sure what's going on with that.  It almost looks like the black background has some transparency, and a checkerboard background from p'shop is showing through.  The key thing tho is that your text images look okay.